# I want to use an existing repo in Bitbucket(stash) which no one is using now

Tags: bitbucket

I want to use an existing repo in Bitbucket(stash) which was created by some other developer for his project and currently not in use. This repo already has some old project in it. When i am pushing my local git project to this repo i am getting error "Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally"

Comment: Have you followed the instructions given in that error message?

Comment: Just create a new repository for yourself.  Repositories are cheap!  Why would you want to reuse someone else's?  If you're trying to work around onerous corporate policy (e.g., "new repositories require manager signoff" and things like that), it's best to just do what your company expects, even if it seems annoying. They have their reasons. (Pure speculation on my part about that being the possible reason for this question...)

Comment: The reason I am loathe to suggest the technical answer is because there are two options, extreme opposites of each other, and both are insane: 1.) git pull or 2.) git push --force.   (Akin to either permanently grafting two unrelated projects together, or completely deleting someone else's work).